# ttk Styling doesn't work inside functions

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have some ttk buttons but they're inside a function and whenever I try to style it it doesn't work but when I create a new file and use same lines but without putting it inside functions it works just fine. Here's the snippet of code.

```
def function():
    if Something == Another thing: 
        r = Tk() # Opens new window
        r.title('Lorem ipsum')
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('TButton', font=('Helvetica', 18))
        Button = ttk.Button(r, text = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",command = lorem ipsum,style="TButton")
        Label = ttk.Label(r, text = "Get total Stores Values and quantities")
        Label.place(relx = 0.2, rely= 0.4,anchor=CENTER)
        Button.place(relx = 0.5, rely= 0.4 ,width= 500 ,height = 50  ,anchor=CENTER)
```

Thanks and hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Comment: Try `s = ttk.Style(r)`.  But using multiple `Tk()` is not recommended.

Comment: I know it's not advised and it's not the best solution but the whole thing makes it a necessity and I must use multiple instances of Tk().

Anyway I need the solution to this on its current state.

@acw1668 Sadly, this still doesn't work but thanks for the effort :) .

Comment: But it works in both my Linux and Windows running Python 3.

Comment: Your styles apply well on my windows system. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't show any errors. It just doesn't apply the styling. I really don't know what to do.I'm also using Windows so it should work. I'll check again and try to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: @SomrajChowdhury
I just thought of something. Maybe the problem is with the imports. What imports did you use and I'll check if there's something missing. Thanks a ton.

Comment: See my example [`here`](https://pastebin.com/xQqgsYrZ).

Comment: Thank you very very much. It worked. You can post it in an answer so I can give you the answer points I guess. I'm sorry but I don't know much about stackoverflow I'm just a newcomer. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are multiple `Tk()` instances, you need to specify which instance the style belongs to:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def function():
    if True:
        r = Tk() # Opens new window
        r.geometry('600x400')
        r.title('Lorem ipsum')
        s = ttk.Style(r) # should specify which Tk instance
        s.configure('TButton', font=('Helvetica', 18))
        Button = ttk.Button(r, text="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", style="TButton")
        Label = ttk.Label(r, text="Get total Stores Values and quantities")
        Label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=CENTER)
        Button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, width=500, height=50, anchor=CENTER)

root = Tk()
function()
root.mainloop()
```

Note that you used `TButton` as the style name which affects all the `ttk.Button()` (actually you can remove `style="TButton"`). Better to use other name like `Custom.TButton` if you want to apply the style to particular widgets only.

Avoid using multiple `Tk()` instances.  Use `Toplevel()` if you can.